# Logging framework on Xamarin iOS

Tags: .net, ios, logging, xamarin.ios, xamarin

What's the state of logging on `Xamarin.iOS` (using Xamarin Studio Indie).

I've tried using `NLog`, but it references `System.ServiceModel` - so Xamarin complains that I need business edition (not paying that much just to use `NLog!`)

log4net also doesn't work, because it references classes in `System.Configuration` that don't exist in `Xamarin/MonoTouch`.

I find it surprising that there isn't a logging solution available, either in with XS, or by the major logging players.

What am  missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Logging on iOS is a bit different than logging on a desktop/server application, as the user has no (easy) way to retrieve the logs.

There are multiple options though:

1. For your own debugging purposes:

   use `System.Console.WriteLine()`. That's equivalent to Obj-C `NSLog`
2. For remote logging:

   use a third party framework e.g.

   - TestFlight SDK (for beta testing, but there's a private beta for production builds as well)
   - Crashlytics

   Some solutions even provide remote logging, so you can have access to crash reports and device logs.

   It goes without saying that you can use most of these frameworks from Xamarin.iOS, check https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings

Comment: For remote logging Xamarin Insights is good option: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/insights/application/#Logging_Reports_to_Xamarin_Insights

Answer (score 6):

I think you can use Xamarin Insights for logging.
[Xamarin Insights](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.xamarin.com%2Fguides%2Fcross-platform%2Finsights%2Fapplication%2F&ei=mOgIVd6FJJKTuATxtICACA&usg=AFQjCNG2K7A-i_yBHPIP1ciBBgdtL3VSeQ&sig2=2Edv9B_cvdY-nwGnD2J-cg&bvm=bv.88198703,d.c2E)

Comment: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/insights/application/#Logging_Reports_to_Xamarin_Insights

Answer (score 3):

I forked Apache log4net and made it compile under MonoTouch with some essential appenders. Expect bugs since it's not fully tested, but it's a start.

[monotouch-log4net @ GitHub](https://github.com/drunkirishcoder/monotouch-log4net)

Answer (score 2):

[Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com) just released an official crash reporting and logging framework for Xamarin (Full disclosure: I'm one of the co-founders).  It has full support for automatically logging unhandled exceptions and signals (signals like SIGSEGV are handled gracefully by letting the Mono runtime handle them and pass the full stacktrace to Crittercism).  You can also send any logs to Crittercism as well using handled exception logging.  You can download it from the Xamarin store here:

http://components.xamarin.com/view/crittercism